# How to allow for multiple variables in one query without causing multiple arguments?

Tags: python, sqlite

my current line of code is as follows

```
c.execute("UPDATE " + str(table), "SET " + str(fieldchoice), " = " + str(newvalue), "WHERE " + str(tableid), "=" + str(idchoice))
```

im trying to get a value in a table chosen by the user to update by fulfilling specific criteria the user enters, but when i try and run it, it gives me the error:

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
function takes at most 2 arguments (5 given)
  File "C:\Users\leoau\Documents\Actual NEA Project code.py", line 230, in updaterecord
    c.execute("UPDATE " + str(table), "SET " + str(fieldchoice), " = " + str(newvalue), "WHERE " + str(tableid), "=" + str(idchoice))
  File "C:\Users\leoau\Documents\Actual NEA Project code.py", line 38, in menu
    updaterecord()
  File "C:\Users\leoau\Documents\Actual NEA Project code.py", line 306, in <module>
    menu()
```

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What is the `c.execute` method?

Comment: You almost certainly need a single string, not separate string arguments based on arbitrary line breaks.

Comment: if this is an exercise in dynamic query building i could see this being useful, but if you want this kind of thing implemented in a tested way: have a look at SQLAlchemy.

Answer (score 0):

The code is passing 4 arguments to `execute`, comma delimited. It would *look like* a valid sql if passed to `print`. But it is still 4 arguments. Use `+` instead of `,` when creating the query string.